# Group texting with Android users and iPhone not staying as group

Tags: iphone, messages, android, group

I have an iPhone 8+ and one of my friend is sending group texts to me and some buddies.
I can see the group discussion, but when I reply, they all receive my text individually, not in the actual group conversation.

2 of my friends are also using an iPhone, and it's working on their end.
What's weird is that I see in the group discussion that my messages are there, but my friends are all saying they are receiving it individually.

I have checked in my Settings > Messages, and "MMS messaging" is checked, and "SMS" too.
I have no idea why it's happening. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Have you enabled "Group Messaging"? This can be found in Settings > Messages and in the SMS/MMS section. Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, if it does, then let me know so that I can create an answer to this post.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I had all those things checked and it worked after updating the iPhone to the latest version. Thanks again